# Python: dynamic list names

Tags: python, list, dynamic

I'm trying to put together a file that accepts inputs from a user as to a number of text files they want analyzed. As a first step, I want to just take the contents of each document they input (can be any number, no limit) and record the contents of each line of the document as an item in a list. I'd like to have a separate list for each document that the user inputs, but that is where I'm struggling. Below is what I've got so far.

```
def user_input():
    prompt = raw_input("Please input the full name (e.g. text_file.txt) or path of a text file:")
    global lst
    lst = {}
    lst[0] = prompt
    global file_count
    file_count = 1
    while len(prompt) > 0:
        prompt = raw_input("Please input any additional text files or simply press enter to continue:")
        if len(prompt) > 0:
            lst[file_count] = prompt
            file_count = file_count+1
    return lst

def read_in():
    for x in lst.values():
        file = open(x)
        x = file.readlines()
```

I'm stuck at this part now as I'm not sure how to dynamically assign names to each list. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Whenever you think you need dynamic variables, use a dictionary instead. `somedict[name] = somelist` is always going to be easier than trying to figure out how to set new variables dynamically.

Comment: Defining `lst` and `file_count` as global variables seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_filenames():
    filelist = []
    prompts = [
        "Please input the full name (e.g. text_file.txt) or path of a text file:",
        "Please input any additional text files or simply press enter to continue:"
    ]
    while True:
        filename = raw_input(prompts[len(filelist) > 0]).strip()
        if not filename:
            break
        filelist.append(filename)
    return filelist

def get_filelines(filelist):
    files = {}
    for filename in filelist:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            files[filename] = fp.readlines()
    return files

if __name__=='__main__':
    print get_filelines(get_filenames())
```